# Adding headers to every response of an Blazor WASM in .NET 6

Tags: http-headers, blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0

I created a simple (so far) Blazor WebAssembly application in .NET 6.

I'm currently adding additional HTTP requests to every response of the application and wanted to add an X-FRAME-OPTIONS header, but when searching on how to do it, I realized I don't know how to approach it.

For starters here's my `Program.cs` file:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using MyApplicationNamespace;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

When reading [this webpage](https://code-maze.com/aspnetcore-add-custom-headers/) I learned about using middleware inside

```cs
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add("x-my-custom-header", "middleware response");
    await next();
});
```

I do understand [from this site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) that in order to use the Use function I can do this:

```
var app = builder.Build();
app.Use();
```

Or that I can just pass a delegate function

```cs
app.Run(async context =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello from 2nd delegate.");
});
```

Point is, in `Blazor WASM` I don't have a Run method, and RunAsync does not take parameters.

I'm not sure where to go from here to add a header?

Am I missing a NuGet passage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've learned from [this person on Twitter](https://twitter.com/PhoenixHawk/status/1511614155417169921):

> The Blazor WASM application is the client. It lives exclusively within the browser. It is receiving responses from a web server, and not "returning" anything. X-Frame-Options headers need to be set on the server, not by the application in the Browser.
>
> Do you mean that the web server should add these headers when it's delivering the (static) files of your Blazor application to the browser before it starts being executed there? **You need to configure your web server (whatever it is) to send these headers then.**

Since I deployed my application as an **Azure App Service** I used Advanced Tools to edit out `web.config` inspired by [this site](https://www.azuretechguy.com/modifying-response-headers-in-azure-app-service).